# Have a dwarf build a wall one Z level lower than he is

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is it possible to either have a dwarf build a wall one Z level lower than he is standing or else "fill in" a ramp one Z level lower? I find that when I have a pit with a ramp leading up inside I can fill every tile in the pit but the ramp, but then can't fill the ramp (to get that OCD required completely filled in pit).

I realize I could just build a floor over the ramp, but that would result in a horrible ramp-void under the floor.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. As an alternative, you could try caving in a portion of natural stone/dirt, or creating obsidian from water and magma.

Comment: Does a block that is dropped via cave-in replace a ramp on the tile it drops onto?

Comment: It destroys ramps and floors, stopping only on filled blocks. More info [here](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.34:Cave-in).